# UpdatePanel.Update() not updating in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

This leads on from a problem with another thread....but is more focussed on one point hopefully!

I've got an AJAX update Panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel
     ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
           <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" runat="server" />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage2" runat="server" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnTrigger" runat="server"        onclick="Button1_Click" style="visibility:hidden"/>

              </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my code behind is this

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Type cstype = this.GetType();
        Label message1 = (Label)(FindControl("lblMessage1"));
        Label message2 = (Label)(FindControl("lblMessage2"));

        message1.Text = "adam";
        UpdatePanel1.Update();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        message2.Text = "adam2";
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

I want to see Adam appear and then Adam2 after 5 seconds, but they both appear together.

Comment: I've set up the scriptmanager by the way...<asp:ScriptManager ID="scmSubmit" runat="server">
                                    </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: I think you need to learn about the differences between client-side code and server-side code, and exactly what happens at each end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided will set the value in `message1.Text` ON THE SERVER, wait 5 seconds ON THE SERVER, and then set `message2.Text` ON THE SERVER... it will then send everything back to the client in one go.  That is why you're seeing it all update at the same time.

If you want them to be updated at different times, you will need more complex coding to call two separate things on the server, and display them independently.

For that, you're probably going to have to look at TWO `<asp:UpdatePanel>` objects, or write your own AJAX handling code in javascript/jquery

Comment: Thanks guys....i'm new to AJAX and the MSDN descriptions made me think I could do it...i'll issue a client call on the way back to re-invoke another postback....

Comment: Don't quote me on this, @Adam, but try looking at the `<Trigger>` element of the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.  You should be able to automatically set two panels off at the same time, one of which could have your in-built "sleep" to give the delay

Comment: @freefaller You wouldn't want to do it that way.  You'd want to do the first request normally, then return to the client, then use a `Timer` to have the client fire a second postback after a set period of time, then handle the second postback.

Comment: In that case, I **definitely** wouldn't quote me on it ;-) Thanks @Servy, I've relatively little experience with UpdatePanels (I generally write my own AJAX handlers) so I am happy to bow to your comments

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Update` on the panel, but since it's occurring on the server side, both calls are essentially executed on the client at the same time.  Calling `Update` has no effect until the call is returned.  You would need two separate calls, or a client side trigger to make it behave the way you have described.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate 2 labels, 2 buttons into 2 different update panels. Then trigger them continuously one after another 5 seconds:

HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel
     ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
           <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnTrigger1" runat="server"        onclick="Button1_Click" style="visibility:hidden"/>
              </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel
     ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
           <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblMessage2" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnTrigger2" runat="server"        onclick="Button2_Click" style="visibility:hidden"/>
           </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
     window.onload = function(){
          document.getElementById("<%= btnTrigger1.ClientID %>").click();
          // wait 5 secs to trigger 2nd button
          setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("<%= btnTrigger2.ClientID %>").click();
          }, 5000);
     };
</script>
```

CS:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    Label message1 = (Label)(FindControl("lblMessage1"));

    message1.Text = "adam";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    Label message2 = (Label)(FindControl("lblMessage2"));

    message2.Text = "adam2";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```